# Can any user use the external user's site invitation link to access the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, share, external-users

I am working on sharepoint online inside office 365. and i configured the following setting for our site collection external sharing:-

[image]

now let say i shared the site (add external user to the members group) with this account `1***23456789@hotmail.com` or account such as `1***23456789@XY**.com`. where this external user will receive an email invitation with the site link.

but my question is, in theory could any other external user, reuse the invitation link, and access the site?? or at the end the sharepoint site will check if the external user who is trying to access the site is the same as the user which the invitation email were sent to (or at-least will check if the user has already been sent an invitation email)?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, this was a setting where you could choose if the e-mail address of the person receiving the invitation should be the same as the user accepting it. I think they removed this setting and made it the default. If you want to be sure, it's best to test it.

It does give some challenges, as people without Office 365 need to create an Microsoft account based on their work e-mail.